# replace all items other than english alphabets,digits and keyboard symbols with nothing in php string

Tags: php, regex, utf-8

I have a php string  which may contain chinese and other symbols which are not utf8. I need to remove all these and need to maintain only English alphabets,digits and common symbols and white space.

I tried a regex like this

```
    $text = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', ' ', $words);
```

But I am not getting the desired output.
My string will be like this :

```
l 2014 ;59:316 �猫聦聙 Efficacy and Safety of Terbinafine Hydrochloride 1% Cream vs. Sertaconazole Nitrate 2% Cream in Tinea Corporis and Tinea Cruris: A Comparative Therapeutic Trial .Indian Journal of Dermatology 2013 ;58(6):457 - 460 �猫聦聙 Congenital cutis laxa with rectal and uterovaginal prolapse. Indian J Dermatol Venereol Leprol 2011 ;77:321 - 4 �猫聦聙 Dermatitis neglecta. Indian J Dermatol Venereol Leprol 2011 ;77:62 - 3 �猫聦聙 Ichthyosis bullosa of Siemens sans history of blistering: an interesting case report Journal of Pakistan Association of Dermatologists 2009 ; 19: 171 - 174 Paper presentations �猫聦聙 Study of Autologous Serum Skin Test In Chronic Idiopathic Urtic aria at Cuticon conference , Dec 2010 �猫聦聙 Scenerio of Leprosy at Tertiary Care Level Centre In Rural Central India at Cuticon conference , Nov 2009 Poster presentations �猫聦聙 Extrav
```

I want to remove `�猫聦聙` like things.

Comment: I tried this...what about symbols?

Comment: like ;'/.;[]'-)(*<>?&^%$#@!~}{|\/

Comment: *But I am not getting the desired output.* - What output do you get?

Comment: I need symbols also to be retained

Comment: `[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?]*` will this work

Comment: Try  `preg_replace('/[^[:ascii:]]+/', '', $words);` to remove any non ASCII symbols.

Comment: Could you please add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to retain only printable ASCII characters and wants to get rid of the rest.

You can use this regex, which will retain all printable ascii characters and removes rest of the characters,

```
[^ -~]+
```

This regex basically uses ranged character set starting from space to last ascii character which is tilde.

**[Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/3ZmeSh/1)**

Let me know if this works for you. If you want to further exclude some more characters from ASCII list too, that can be easily done. Just let me know.

PHP code demo,

```
$words = "l 2014 ;59:316 �猫聦聙 Efficacy and Safety of Terbinafine Hydrochloride 1% Cream vs. Sertaconazole Nitrate 2% Cream in Tinea Corporis and Tinea Cruris: A Comparative Therapeutic Trial .Indian Journal of Dermatology 2013 ;58(6):457 - 460 �猫聦聙 Congenital cutis laxa with rectal and uterovaginal prolapse. Indian J Dermatol Venereol Leprol 2011 ;77:321 - 4 �猫聦聙 Dermatitis neglecta. Indian J Dermatol Venereol Leprol 2011 ;77:62 - 3 �猫聦聙 Ichthyosis bullosa of Siemens sans history of blistering: an interesting case report Journal of Pakistan Association of Dermatologists 2009 ; 19: 171 - 174 Paper presentations �猫聦聙 Study of Autologous Serum Skin Test In Chronic Idiopathic Urtic aria at Cuticon conference , Dec 2010 �猫聦聙 Scenerio of Leprosy at Tertiary Care Level Centre In Rural Central India at Cuticon conference , Nov 2009 Poster presentations �猫聦聙 Extrav";
echo preg_replace('/[^ -~]+/', '', $words);
```

Prints only your intended characters.

```
l 2014 ;59:316  Efficacy and Safety of Terbinafine Hydrochloride 1% Cream vs. Sertaconazole Nitrate 2% Cream in Tinea Corporis and Tinea Cruris: A Comparative Therapeutic Trial .Indian Journal of Dermatology 2013 ;58(6):457 - 460  Congenital cutis laxa with rectal and uterovaginal prolapse. Indian J Dermatol Venereol Leprol 2011 ;77:321 - 4  Dermatitis neglecta. Indian J Dermatol Venereol Leprol 2011 ;77:62 - 3  Ichthyosis bullosa of Siemens sans history of blistering: an interesting case report Journal of Pakistan Association of Dermatologists 2009 ; 19: 171 - 174 Paper presentations  Study of Autologous Serum Skin Test In Chronic Idiopathic Urtic aria at Cuticon conference , Dec 2010  Scenerio of Leprosy at Tertiary Care Level Centre In Rural Central India at Cuticon conference , Nov 2009 Poster presentations  Extrav
```

**[Online PHP demo](https://rextester.com/LKCVYL23663)**